# How to fix this badly designed code

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        #region BaseAddress

      Process[] test = Process.GetProcessesByName(process); //Get process handle
      if (test.Any())
      {

          int Base = test[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
      }
        #endregion
       //lots of other code blocks
     }
```

I now want to take the region 'BaseAddress' out of the timer1_Tick control to make the code more efficient and have it run once at the beginning of the program. The other code in this control makes frequent use of the variable 'Base', what is the best way to make this globally accessible without having to go back through all the instances that use Base and do something like MyGlobals.Base, for example?

Comment: Why exactly, does this code exist in the first place? What is the point of it?

Comment: To get the base address of a running process for use in ReadProcessMemory.

Comment: First, refactor that name `Base` to something different. Just because C# is case sensitive is not a good reason to name a variable like a reserved keyword.

Comment: I have named all of my variables with capitals at the beginning :O

Comment: @user1166981 - While it's technically allowed, it's generally frowned upon since it conflicts with class notation and makes your code harder to read. Normally in .NET, classes are named in `PascalCase` style, and variables with `camelCase` style (note the lower case 'c' at the beginning.

Comment: I see, ok, I will do that from now on.

Comment: @user1166981 - The problem isn't the casing. The problem is your use of the word `Base`. The lowercase form, `base`, [is a reserved word in C# that refers to the base class your class derives from](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfw7t1ce.aspx). Naming a variable after a reserved keyword is a much bigger problem than using the wrong casing convention.

Comment: Ok, both points understood. thanks

Comment: You should use `IntPtr` if it all possible, that way your code will work in 64bit as well.

Comment: Someone else told me that recently, but its strange, my system is 64 bit, but the application I am reading memory is 32 so maybe thats why its still ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lazy load the address into a static variable.  It won't initialize until you use it for the first time, then will remain in memory for the life of the application.

```
public static MyGlobals
{
    private static readonly Lazy<int> _processBase = new Lazy<int>(() => GetProcessBase("MyProcessName"));

    // I don't recommend using the word Base, but OK...
    public static int Base { get { return _processBase.Value; } }

    private static int GetProcessBase(string processName)
    {
        int b = 0;
        Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName);
        if(p != null && p.Length > 0)
        {
            b = p[0].MainModule.BaseAddress.ToInt32();
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

In some other part of the app...

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if(MyGlobals.Base > 0)
    {
         // TODO: change "Base" to "MyGlobals.Base" in code below or it won't compile...
         //lots of other code blocks 
    }
}
```

Comment: I get errors still: MainModule does not exist in the current context, and the same Base does not exist in the current context for all the other code blocks in the timer control

Comment: Sorry.. coding freehand from memory.  I fixed it.

Comment: Ok, now the mainmodule error has gone, but the original Base does not exist errors are throughout the timer control

Comment: Change "Base" everywhere to _processBase.Value, or set the variable you're using to _processBase.Value.  I don't have the rest of your code to correct those errors.

Comment: Ah. I was hoping to avoid going through all the code as I was going to just set Base as a global and then replace all Base with MyGlobals.Base. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: And feel free to rename the variables and function names, to i.e. GetProcessBaseAddress, _processBaseAddr, etc... whatever makes your code more readable to you.

Comment: Yes, that can be accomplished as well.  I don't have your MyGlobals code, but I can mock something up for that as well... one sec...

Comment: `processBase` is certainly a strange name for the base address of the main module.

Comment: Hmm after changing Base to processBase I am getting the same errors, but now for processBase? (thanks so much for helping me by the way, I learn a lot from your guys)

Comment: @user1166981 - see the update, I changed it to fit your code using "MyGlobals.Base".

Comment: Ok, I put in the code, sorry for my newbness, but how do I initialise it? as currently when the timer starts it wont go any further than the first line as process base hasn't been instructed to do anything yet

Comment: @user1166981 - as soon as you attempt to use it, it will automatically initialize.  If the value is zero, it might be because you don't have the correct name.  Have you also looked into EntryPointAddress?

Comment: ok, I don't know, its compiling with no errors, but MyGlobals.Base is empty for some reason. Are you saying that this line: "if(MyGlobals.Base > 0)" initialises it?

Comment: @user1166981 - yes.  Set a breakpoint in the private method 'GetProcessBase' and you'll see.

Answer (score 0):

The method I would use in this case would be to create a singleton class **ProcessFetcher** (for example) with a **Base** property.

My class would have a **fetch()** function and **isDataPresent** property.

You can decide to call fetch manually or put it on the constructor.

Comment: Won't I have to still make modifications to all of the other code that references Base?

Comment: A simple replace should do the trick: Base => ProcessFetcher.Instance.Base